# Z390 HD Gigabyte - new build - no POST or Boot

Tags: boot, motherboard, post

So it's not my first rodeo building a PC, but it's been a few years since I have needed to. 
We're going with a Gigabyte Z390 UD, i7 9700K CPU, 4x8GB RAM which is rated to 4000MHz and a nice 8GB Radeon graphics card.

At present, I'm able to power-on into the BIOS. the board came with F8 and with the thing not progressing beyond a bios save, I've updated to F10e which is the latest available from Gigabyte.

I can't get it to progress past putting a small white underscore in the top left of the screen. There's no indications on the mother board of any issues but it's not getting past the initialization stage. I know the USB ports are working because I pulled off the BIOS flash from one of my memory sticks.

So, anyone got any ideas?

EDIT:

so there's no audible indication (no beeps). At the present time, the MB is booting into bios and then as soon as I attempt a "save and exit" we boot straight back into the bios again. The case I am building this box into doesn't have a beeper, so that's probably not helping the situation and is probably the number one reason why the MB isn't beeping. No errors on screen and no indications on the MB.

Comment: You indicate that you are able to get into the BIOS, which means you are POST-ing. You should also be able to get into the boot menu as well. See if you can do that with the USB stick inserted and see if it even shows up as a boot option. If not, confirm that the USB is indeed bootable by putting it in another PC and attempting the same boot menu startup.

Comment: Hey Sam - the reason I am unsure whether it is not performing a POST is that there is no visible indication of a POST operation occurring. Seems to just lock up right before this happens. I am able to get into bios, but unless I'm quick, the terminal just locks. There is no indication that the M2 Drive or the USB drive no O/S installed (which it doesn't). Will confirm with another machine I have here, but I suspect some sort of compatibility issue. Just unsure as to how to diagnose.

Comment: @Mark - There typically isn't any indication that a motherboard is able to POST other than the fact, it displays an error, indicating it wasn't successful. It certainly sounds like a device error might be causing something to happen.  Does this motherboard display error codes or is everything done through an audio beep?  Instead of replying with another comment you should edit your question.